# How to delete a file after vlc finishes playing it?

Tags: windows-7, vlc-media-player

I know you can have vlc shut down your pc after you finish playing something but I'm trying to figure out a way to delete the file, preferably with a confirmation dialog box after you finish playing something.  Ideally it would only do this if the file was actually played to at least 90% of the file so as not to have unnecessary deletions but that may not be possible.  Running a batch file to play the video would work, but it'd have to be something easy to do.  Having to edit a batch file with the name of the video to play each time would get old fast.  Any ideas?

Comment: Make an app that launches videos while also taking care of these things for you?

Comment: I was hoping to find something that was already built though I have been considering that option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use something like this maybe?

Prerequisites:

- Add the location of VLC Player to the [PATH variable](https://superuser.com/q/284342/167187)

```
@ECHO OFF
CMD /C "vlc --play-and-exit %*"
REM wait a second before deleting
ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 1000 > nul
del /F /Q %*
PAUSE
```

Save that as `VLCPlayAndDelete.bat` and drop files onto the batch script like so:

[image: Drag and drop files]

The files will be deleted when VLC finishes playing all the files that were dropped onto the script.

Comment: Change `del /F /Q %*` to `del /F /P %*` to be prompted before deleting files.

Comment: Helpful image with your answer. How did you make that?

Comment: @root: That's an animated GIF image and you can make those easily using [LICEcap](http://www.cockos.com/licecap/)

Answer (score 1):

You can make of [pot player](http://potplayer.daum.net/) for the purpose. Press `Shift+del` to delete the video while it plays.